# Gradle doesnt support newest libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, libraries

I have updated parts of the  Android sdk and now I can use newer versions of my libraries but the gradle file doesn't accept them. Can you help me pls?
That one is the only projects where it get an error, that's why I think it gets the error 'cause of a local project file.
I got a failed to resolve error  at each library 
I use some of Google firebase (11.2.0) ;support:appcompat-v7(26.0.2); support:design (26.0.2)

Android studio says me that are the newest versions for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Play services and Firebase dependencies are now available via `maven.google.com` with the release of version `11.2.0` of Google Play services and Firebase.

Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For more information please check official [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120)

Comment: Tanks this solves my problem :D